# How add variable to email body

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a problem with the variable. I want to put it in the content of the email, unfortunately all attempts end in failure. In Powershell this is my first script, I have experience in programming. I want to add **$PasswordTillExpired** variable in the content of the email:

```
$emailBody = @"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-
transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<b><p>Your password will expire soon! $PasswordTillExpired</p></b>
<p>Please change password at xxx password reset'</a> or contact Helpdesk.</p>
<p><br>More information about changing your password and instructions can be found</p></b>
<p>Greetings,</p>
<p>Helpdesk IT</p>
</body>
</html>
"@
```

Comment: It works fine for me, are you sure you have the correct value assigned to the variable?

Comment: Yes, only this variable is defined later in the loop, so you don't 'update' the email content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, only this variable is defined later in the loop, so you don't 'update' the email content. – markiewicz36 5 mins ago

Variable Expansion in PowerShell works differently.  In order to expand a variable inside a string, the Variable must be defined *before* you assign the string.

To illustrate, this will not work.

```
$Body = " Hello, $user !"
$user = "FoxDeploy"

Write-Host $Body
" Hello, !"
```

While this will:

```
$user = "FoxDeploy"
$Body = " Hello, $user !"

Write-Host $Body
" Hello, FoxDeploy!"
```

You simply need to move your variable assignment down into an area in your script where `$PasswordTillExpired` has a meaningful value.

**To Preserve your Present Approach**

If you really want to use the approach you have today, of assigning the e-mail body at the top of the script, you could use `-Replace` to swap a token out.

So, you'd change `$PasswordTillExpired` to something like `%PasswordTillExpiredToken`, then make a new instance of the e-mail body when you need it, like this:

```
$thisEmailBody = $emailBody -replace "%PasswordTillExpiredToken", $PasswordTillExpired
```

That will give you a new `$thisEmailBody` customized for that user.

Comment: Thank you very much. I put the $emailBody value in the loop and now it works just as I expected!

Answer (score 2):

As you want to assign the value after assigning value to `$emailBody`, you can simply replace it:

```
$emailBody =  @'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-
transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<b><p>Your password will expire soon! $PasswordTillExpired</p></b>
<p>Please change password at xxx password reset'</a> or contact Helpdesk.</p>
<p><br>More information about changing your password and instructions can be found</p></b>
<p>Greetings,</p>
<p>Helpdesk IT</p>
</body>
</html>
'@

# Set the variable here
$PasswordTillExpired = "SOMETHING SOMETHING"

$personalizedEmailBody = $emailBody.replace('$PasswordTillExpired',$PasswordTillExpired)
```

Note that I changed `@" (...) "@` to `@' (...) '@` so that the literal value is saved to the variable. See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1) for more info.

I'd also suggest using different string such as `####### PasswordTillExpired #####`. You can avoid having issues if someone replaces single quotes with double quotes in the future.